# what is the best way to reuse code between NodeJS and React/Webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, export, reusability

I'm writing an app which consist a NodeJS backend and a React (built by Webpack) frontend.
I have a few bits (enums, functions, etc.) I'd like to share between the two sides e.g.

```
 BookRequestStatus = {
    pending: 'pending',
    ordered: 'ordered',
    available: 'available',
    rejected: 'rejected',
    unconfirmed: 'unconfirmed',
    missing: 'missing'
}
```

but I'm struggling to find a way I can export/import/require these on both sides.
(either one seems to work, or the other, but not both).
Could someone give a working example for this please?

Comment: you have to expose them via Rest APIs in node.js backend

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js to using `import` keyword, you can use `babel/node` module

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/node
```

then running the server like this

```
npx babel-node server.js
```